# How to specify which element to change background color jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a simple website where I have a slideshow.

The pictures slide is automatic and on the right side of the page I have a menu with 6 buttons. When I press "button1" the picture for "button1" appears, when I click on "button2" the picture for "button2" appears etc.

What I want to do:

When my slideshow changes that one of the 6 buttons gets their background color change to indicate that the picture that is being displayed has a relation to that button.

Example:

```
Slideshow:
picture1 appears -----> button1 gets background color changed
picture2 appears -----> button2 gets background changed 
etc.
```

My code for this:

```
$(".showcase-thumbnail-content").removeClass("active, passive"); 
$(".showcase-thumbnail-content").addClass("active");
```

This works with the problem that all the buttons get their color changed not just one at the time.

All buttons are in the `div` with class `showcase-thumbnail-content`
I have thought about creating a separate `div` for each button but my main question is:

**How do make it so that only "button1" gets the background color changed when "picture1" is displayed on the slideshow??**

I have tried being as through as I can, if more info is needed just ask.

Edit:

Since there is alot of code on the page i don´t exaactly know what parts would be most relevant here so if any1 would take the time and look here:

http://showcase.awkwardgroup.com/index2.html

I am working with demo 2, with my own modifications.

The following changes have been done:

**css:**

```
.showcase-thumbnail-content {
    /* padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px; */

    background: #ededed;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #777;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 0.8em arial, sans-serif;
    width: 120px;
    font-size: 130%;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}
            }
.showcase-thumbnail-content:hover {
    color:#F77B0F!Important;
}

.active {
    background: red;
}
```

**html changes:**

**showcase-slide:**

```
<div class="showcase-slide">
            <!-- Put the slide content in a div with the class .showcase-content. -->
            <div class="showcase-content">
                <img src="images/01.jpg" alt="01" />
            </div>
            <!-- Put the thumbnail content in a div with the class .showcase-thumbnail -->
            <div class="showcase-thumbnail">
                <!-- <img src="images/01.jpg" alt="01" width="140px" /> -->
                <!-- The div below with the class .showcase-thumbnail-caption contains the thumbnail caption. -->
                <p class="showcase-thumbnail-content">First</p>
                <!-- The div below with the class .showcase-thumbnail-cover is used for the thumbnails active state. -->
                <!-- <div class="showcase-thumbnail-cover"></div> -->
            </div>
            <!-- Put the caption content in a div with the class .showcase-caption -->
            <div class="showcase-caption">
                <h2>Be creative. Get Noticed!</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
```

// This is done for all the six elements(exactly the same)

The script code is the same as in demo2 with the modification that i have shown above.

If more info is needed just ask.

Comment: @user1862808, you should add revelant parts of you markup / JS code or even better provide a jsFiddle.

Comment: a quick look but `removeClass` is space-separated not with a comma now you are removing a class named `active,` and `passive` you should write `removeClass("active passive")`

Comment: That doesn´t help, i get the background color changed when calling the class active the problem is that it changes the color on all the element at once instead of on at a time. I think that i need to have a unic css class for each element but i still don´t know how to write code that changes the color of a specific element when a specific picture/slide is displayed

Comment: as @RC. writes try to make an example running on jsfiddle. your code says find all `.showcase-thumbnail-content` and remove the classes and then add one class again on all the elements found on the page, and idea is to find the index you have on the image and add the class on the same index on your `.showcase-tumbnail-content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from a friend i solved this.

It would seem that i had missed some code in the demo.

the following script was in it:

```
if (options.thumbnails)
                    {
                        i = 0;
                        showcase.find('.showcase-thumbnail').each(function()
                        {
                            var object = jQuery(this);
                            object.removeClass('active');
                            if (i === current_id) { object.addClass('active'); }
                            i++;
                        });
                    }
```

And in the css I had :

```
showcase-thumbnail.active p
        {
            color: blue;

        }
```

Hope this will help others in the future!

Answer (score 0):

example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4K4FW/2/). jquery script example is as follow:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')==true)
  {
     $(this).removeClass("active"); 
     $(this).addClass("passive"); 
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    $(this).removeClass("passive"); 
  }
 });​
```

Comment: This will be usefull later on thanks! But for the current question i dont know if it helps. Since the element that is matched with piceture1 should get the attributes from the class "active" and when the picture changes then the old element should return to passive and the new element gets active etc.

Comment: To clarify :

when the slideshow picture changes the element that is assosiated with the picture gets the attributes from the active class, when the picture changes again the old element gets the passive attribiutes and the new one gets the active attributes.

Comment: same principle apply. Maybe what you need is the change event http://api.jquery.com/change/ , but same principle apply for sure

Comment: A friend helped me find a soloution but we expremineted with yours and it works, will accept your answer, thanks!